# Tridion workflow addon is not active in Microsoft Visio 2010

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We installed Microsoft Visio 2010 Premium on the Tridion 2011 SP1 CMS Server.  We also installed Tridion Workflow designer plug in available in Tridion 2011 SP1 installer.  When we try to access this add-on in Visio 2010 it is displayed under "Inactive Add-on's List"
How to activate this add-on so that we have upload workflow to CMS server and use it?

Comment: I _think_ I saw something like that related to Macro Security in Visio... Can't remember what I did to enable it though, it was some setting in Visio itself.

Comment: Nice question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 5):

First step, make sure that it is properly enabled:

1.- Go to the **Tools** menu, click **Trust Center**, and then click **Add-ins.**

2.- In the Add-ins box, at the botton select **COM Add-ins** and click **Go**

3.- Select the check box for the **TCM Workflow** Add-in

If this is not working, play with the other options of the Trust center, as there is some setting in it, that is blocking it from being loaded